# Jquery Flot not Rendering with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flot

I'm working on a website page which has data updated each 300ms.
For this I use an Ajax call with jQuery. I'm using jQuery flot to render my graphs, but i got an issue when i want realtime ( like in the library example ) rendering.

Here is my code:

```
    var i = 0;
    var datapoints = [];
    var options = {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        },yaxis: {
            min: 40,
            max: 60
        },
        xaxis: {
            show : false
        }
    };
    var plot;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        plot = $.plot("#placeholderplot", [[]], options);
    });
    function loadMesures() {
        setTimeout(loadMesures, 300);
        $.getJSON('http://myurl/', function (data) {
                freq = data.FREQUENCE;
                i++;
                datapoints.push([i, freq])
                plot.setData([datapoints]);
                plot.draw();
                //$.plot("#placeholderplot", [datapoints], options);
        });
    }
```

When i reinitialize the plot with " $.plot("#placeholderplot", [datapoints], options); " my graph renders perfectly but when i use SetData & draw nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  What version of Flot are you using?  Are you using any plugins?

Comment: I've checked there is no error in my console. I've found another way to "simulate" the rendering. Just reinitialize my plot and when i reach the number of points i want in my datapoints, i slice the first point of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just call set data with an array you need to get the data first and set the data property with the array. Also you need to call setup grid so the xaxis can be recalculated.

So try this:

```
i++;
datapoints.push([i, freq]);
var temp = plot.getData();    
temp[0].data = datapoints;
plot.setData(temp);
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/4Uv2a/1/)

Also unless you really need to keep an external reference to the data array you can also do this:

```
var temp = plot.getData();    
temp[0].data.push([i, freq]);
plot.setData(temp);
```

Just another thing, if you need to recalculate the xaxis(e.g. it is not fixed), then calling setData, setupGrid and draw is essentially the same as reinitializing flot. Someone correct me if I am wrong (there used to be a memory leak in previous versions but i believe is resolved in the latest versions).

Comment: Good job it works! Just to notice, for performance you may need to add method to remove useless data (too old) like 
                    if (datapointsfreq.length > 300) {
                        datapointsfreq.splice(0, 1);}

Comment: Sure....it was just an example, I am actually doing a project that plots data in real time, and yes we have a method to remove tail points after a while, operators will leave that window open for days.

Comment: I left the window open ploting for 4 days and I can guarantee no memory leaks on flot!!! Flot is an awesome project!